# Why do i get a type error when using super()?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, superclass, super

I just started learning about classes and inheritance in Python 3. I want to print the name of a student, which is inherited from the superclass Person. Unfortunately I keep getting a TypError.

code:

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name="Mike", age = 25, place_of_birth="Stockholm"):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
        self.place_of_birth = place_of_birth


class Student(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, age, university = "University of Stockholm", gpa = 8):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.university = university
        self.gpa = gpa
```

I then like to print the name of the student by calling:

```
student1 = Student()
print(student1.name)
```

But I keep getting this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'age'

Comment: You haven't given init name and age, as you declared it. `Student()` won't work because you gave it arguments and you're now calling it without.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__()` method of `Student` takes `2` positional arguments: `name` and `age`. You need to specify those arguments when creating a new instance:

```
student1 = Student('eppe2000', 20)
print(student1.name)
```

If you instead want the class `Student` to default to class `Person` default arguments, in case they have not been specified, you can do it like this:

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name="Mike", age=25, place_of_birth="Stockholm"):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
        self.place_of_birth = place_of_birth


class Student(Person):

    def __init__(self, university="University of Stockholm", gpa=8, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.university = university
        self.gpa = gpa


>>> s = Student()
>>> s.name
'Mike'

>>> s = Student(name="Daniele")
>>> s.name
'Daniele'
```

Basically you forward all the keywords arguments that are unknown to the class `Student` to its parent class. Not that if you specify an invalid keyword (i.e: 'surname') you will get a `TypeError` because neither `Student` or `Person` specify a keyword argument with key 'surname'.

If you need info about `**kwargs` check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/3477005

Comment: Thanks. But what I was trying to accomplish was that every new student object created, inherited the 'name' and 'age' attributes from the Person' class, which are initially set to 'Mike' and 25

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Student` to always default to the name and age of the Parent class then you don't want `Student` to take a name and age value.

```
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, university = "University of Stockholm", gpa = 8):
        super().__init__() # runs parent __init__ taking no values
        self.university = university
        self.gpa = gpa

>>> student1 = Student()
>>> student1.name
'Mike'
>>> student1.age
25
```

When you use `super().__init__(name, age)` you are wanting to pass the name and age given to the Student class to the Parent class. But since you don't want to pass anything it is getting errors.

Now, if you want the Student class to be able to take values as well as default to the ones provided by the parent class you can do this.

```
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, name = None, age = None, university = "University of Stockholm", gpa = 8):
        if name is None and age is None:
            super().__init__()
        else:
            super().__init__(name, age)
        self.university = university
        self.gpa = gpa
```

What happens here is if no name or age is provided `if name is None and age is None` then it defaults to the values from `Person` class. However if both the name and age are provided, then it will use those values.

```
>>> student1 = Student()
>>> student1.name
'Mike'
>>> student1.age
25
>>> student2 = Student('Bill', 19)
>>> student2.name
'Bill'
>>> student2.age
19
```

Comment: Thank you both for your clear explanation and swift response! @DanielePantaleone